# Calculate shortest car distance -- repeated over many points

Tags: qgis-3, distance

I am using QGIS 3.10.

I have a dataset with coordinates of many households. Separately I have coordinates of a number of sites. For each of these households, I need to calculate:

1. Which is their closest site by car
2. What is the distance to their closest site by car

Essentially I need to an equivalent of 'Distance to nearest hub' Vector Analysis, but not as the crow flies. I need car distances.

I tried plugin ORS Tools. I got the API key, but I cannot get it to work. There is an error everytime:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/ORStools/proc/directions_points_layers_proc.py", line 248, in processAlgorithm
destination_field
File "Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/ORStools/proc/directions_points_layers_proc.py", line 327, in _get_route_dict
geometries=[xformer_destination.transform(feat.geometry().asPoint()) for feat in destination_feats],
File "Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/ORStools/proc/directions_points_layers_proc.py", line 327, in <listcomp>
geometries=[xformer_destination.transform(feat.geometry().asPoint()) for feat in destination_feats],
ValueError: Null geometry cannot be converted to a point.

Execution failed after 0.23 seconds
```

I don't have to stick with ORS Tools. Is there any solution to do this calculation over many houses?

Comment: Please check geometries of your layers with for example [Geometry Checker Plugin](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/core_plugins/plugins_geometry_checker.html#geometry-checker-plugin). Does it evoke some insufficiencies?

Comment: Thank you! Just checked. It provides me with the following:
Execution completed in 0.26 seconds
Results:
{'ERROR_COUNT': 0,
'ERROR_OUTPUT': 'Error_output_907ffd3d_725c_4f33_bae7_73d3fd4030c6',
'INVALID_COUNT': 0,
'INVALID_OUTPUT': 'Invalid_output_74294d3a_6dbe_401f_b7b3_d8f92cff1b2b',
'VALID_COUNT': 1925,
'VALID_OUTPUT': 'Valid_output_84e43123_bd7e_4fc2_ac0b_d839ed299418'}

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'Check validity' finished

I guess this means there's nothing wrong with my layers?

Comment: I think there is a way to do this using the Google Maps / Routing API... there are academic 'consultants' for DPS that perform bus stop matrix routing problems. Otherwise, we use postgresql/postgis to do this with students and schools.